# In Rails, how could there be a column limit in the staging/production PG database but not for a newly created development PG database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm looking into an error where a user put more than 255 characters in a given field. When I do the same thing locally, I don't get the error because that field's limit isn't set for me locally.  I don't understand why I have that discrepancy. How would that limit be different between my local pg instance, and staging/production?

For example locally:

```
pry(main)> Resume::Education.columns_hash['honors'].limit
=> nil
pry(main)> Resume::Education.columns_hash['honors'].sql_type
=> "character varying"
```

And then on staging:

```
pry(main)> Resume::Education.columns_hash['honors'].limit
=> 255
pry(main)> Resume::Education.columns_hash['honors'].sql_type
=> "character varying(255)"
```

Did Rails change how a :string column is represented in Postgres over time, and since I newly created the database locally, I get the `character varying` version, whereas in production it has an older `character varying(255)`?  What else could account for this?

Comment: Can you share your local database version and your production database version please? Also, have you run the same migrations on both local and production?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it.  https://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#active-record

"The PostgreSQL and SQLite adapters no longer add a default limit of 255 characters on string columns."

Since this table was created before Rails 4.2 (on 4.1.4), it had a 255 character limit on the column.  We have since migrated up through the Rails versions, and when I created my development database instance on Rails 5.2, that limit is not present for me.